# QPDF: reversing order of files to be appended

Tags: windows, globbing

A `qpdf` example indicates:

```
# To merge (concatenate) all the pages of a list of PDF files and save the result as a new PDF:
qpdf --empty --pages <file1.pdf> <file2.pdf> <file3.pdf> -- <output.pdf>
```

A set of .pdf files (with spaces in filenames), in a particular directory, are to be concatenated:

```
# Concatenate Drafts file to ../concatDrafts.pdf   (76 pdf files)
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754681/4953146
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Although [`qpdf` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617493/182280) is concatenates .pdf files, the reverse order of the .pdf files is to be concatenated.  The order of the files to be processed is returned by in UNIX:

```
ls -r.pdf
```

Is there a windows command line equivalent for the [zsh statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617493/182280)?:

```
qpdf --empty --pages ./*.pdf(On) -- output.pdf
```

In particular, it would be nice to understand [Windows globbing qualifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Windows_and_DOS) if any.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question was x-posted on Unix.SE

Comment: Said question is different in its context: Windows not UNIX.  The UNIX solution does not work on Windows.  The question is should stand because, I would like to learn how to implement across different platforms

Comment: @gatorback: Sorry, this was my bad then, I have only read through the first half or so of your question and was misled by the tags. I'll retract my close vote.